# Error in Vue graphql: Missing query attribute on result

Tags: graphql, apollo, vue-apollo, graphql-tag

I want to have multiple queries in one network request. I have put all my queries in vue Apollo but I get this error when data revived(I will get the data in network tab but I cant access it!)

```
error: vue-apollo.esm.js?522d:842 Missing query attribute on result
```

code:

```
apollo: {
    query: gql`
             query {
                 query1 {someValue}
                 query2 {someValue}
             }
          `
}
```